# Endless scroll listner android reset the page no from activity

Tags: android

I have implemented pagination using `EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener`. At a particular scenario I have to reset the page number, so i have created `resetValues()` method. But I don't know how to call this method from activity class.

```
public abstract class EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
        public static String TAG = EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.class.getSimpleName();

        private int previousTotal = 0; // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
        private boolean loading = true; // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
        private int visibleThreshold = 0; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
        int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

        private int current_page = 1;

        private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

        public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager,boolean isfromversion) {
            this.mLinearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
            Log.e("isversionendless",isfromversion+"");
            if(isfromversion)
            {
                resetValues();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (loading) {
                if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                    loading = false;
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                }
            }
            if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                    <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                // End has been reached

                // Do something
                current_page++;

                onLoadMore(current_page);

                loading = true;
            }
        }

        public void resetValues(){
            previousTotal = 0;
            loading = true;
            visibleThreshold = 1;
            firstVisibleItem = 0;
            visibleItemCount = 0;
            totalItemCount = 0;
        }


        public abstract void onLoadMore(int current_page);
    }
```

Comment: This project implement Endless Recyclerview https://github.com/ahmadaghazadeh/EndlessRecyclerview

Answer (score 2):

```
EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener scrollListener=new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(
            mGridLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
            // do somthing...
                loadMoreData(current_page);
        }

    };

    recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
```

when you want to reset values then just simply call method as below.

```
scrollListener.resetValues();
```

Comment: I think it should be scrollListener.resetState();

Comment: This answer is specifically for asked question.